# Why all layers in the view are initially set to nil?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am subclassing `NSButton` for making a round one by following the code online. However, inside the subclass of mine, the `layer` is always `nil`.

I found the similar behavior for other components too, for example `NSView`, to set the property of the layer I need to set `wantsLayer` property of the `NSView` to `true`.

Sample code online

```
@IBInspectable
var shadowOpacity: Float {
    get {
        return layer.shadowOpacity
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
    }
}
```

My code,

```
@IBInspectable
var shadowOpacity: Float {
    get {
        print(layer?)
        return layer.shadowOpacity
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
    }
}
```

My code prints `nil` in the console.

Is there a way to set `wantsLayer` to `true` by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should **override** the default initializers of `NSButton` in your custom class and set `wantsLayer` to `true` there.

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)

    wantsLayer = true
}

override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frameRect)

    wantsLayer = true
}
```